# Allow third-party js to communicate to my vuejs app

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a vuejs app. And I want to add the ability for third-party non-vue js scripts to send commands or data to my app. For example

```
window.app = new Vue({})

app.setTitle = 'Hello'
```

Of course I want to expose only certain methods and triggers.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that `window.app`and it will be sufficient when you do not use webpack. If you use webpack you will have to export the `app` variable.
at
As described in the vue documentation, `new Vue()` returns a proxy object that has access to all methods, data etc. So if you want to export only a few methods you have to create an interface object.

```
var app = new Vue({...});
var interface = {
  methodA: app.methodA,
  methodC: app.methodC
};
```

You can make the events available in a similar way but you better use vuex.

Use vuex if you prefer a global state-object. It's properties can be mapped to each instance and component https://github.com/vuejs/vuex

If you prefer an event based approach use an event bus https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Thanks. Made my day.